# Screen Capture Desktop

Tags: multiple-monitors, monitoring

I'm using an application called Time Clock Wizard that takes screenshots of my desktop at different intervals for the client to see. I was just wondering if there was a way to somehow make it capture just my main display, the reason behind this is I do work for another client which I usually do on my second monitor and they're mostly private information like NDAs and other legal documents that I can't have my time clock wizard capturing. Is there any application or trick that I can use to somehow make this work? Thanks a lot, it would be a lot of help.

Answer (score 0):

The built-in Snipping Tool application for Windows 10 and below (or Snip & Sketch for Windows 11) has an option to only capture a screenshot of a particular window. To use this, open Snipping Tool, click the “Mode” dropdown menu, and select “Window Snip”. (In Windows 11, open Snip & Sketch, click “New” or press Ctrl + N to open a new snip, and then select the third option for Window Snip.) You can then hover over and click the window that you want to send to the client.

If you need the screenshots to capture automatically, perhaps you could set up a script to do this process for you. It should help that there is a keyboard shortcut for opening a new snip, that works for both Snipping Tool and Snip & Sketch: Windows Key + Shift + S will open the tool and default to your most recently used mode (i.e., window snip).

For help with your specific app, you may need to check the manual or ask for technical support. Another alternative that might work for your situation, while continuing to use the application you’re already using, would be to run a virtual machine on one of your monitors and keep the two clients’ work separate. If, for example, you ran all of your first client’s work in the virtual machine window, and ran the screen capture software there, the software would have no access to your second client’s documents or applications running outside of the virtual machine.